# Catch all PHP errors and put them in a string var

Tags: php

How can I catch all PHP errors and put them in a string var?

I suppose I should use set_error_handler().

I am using Ajax + JSON and would like to output the errors in a string and then output them through JSON.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am using Ajax + JSON and would like to output the errors in a string and then output them through JSON.

Comment: Look at php [error_get_last()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) but you need to trace it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's easy:

```
/// Exception handler function
function yourExceptionHandler($exception)
{
    echo '
    <pre>
    <b>Error</b>:  Unhandled '.$exception.'
    occured <b>'.$exception->getFile().'</b> in line <b>'.
    $exception->getLine().'</b><br />
    </pre>';
}
```

And then give this function to php:

```
/// Assign exception handler function
set_exception_handler('yourExceptionHandler');
```

Put this code at the beginning of your php scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?php

try {

// your code block here

} catch (Exception $e) {
  $_my_catch_var = $e->getMessage();
}
```